# Update another table in MySQL when i use "source" command line

Tags: mysql

I have two database and i want to `import/export` form one to other with `source` command line.

The names of my databases is `melka` and `demelka`.

I want to copy form `melka` to `demelka`. for this i follow this steps:

1. Export from `melka` DB and save in `D:/db/melka.sql` and then run this command line
2. ```
    cd D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\bin
   ```
3. ```
    mysql -u root
   ```
4. ```
    USE demelka;
   ```
5. ```
    source D:/db/melka.sql
   ```

#### But after executing the above commands, `melka` Table is updated And `demelka` Table is empty.

Environment:

- I use `WAMP 3.1.7`
- and `mysql5.7.24`

Comment: Open `melka.sql` in any text editor and check at the top that it may have been referencing to `melka` database only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @madhur-bhaiya

I am open my `melka.sql` file in editor and deleted the following commands from within and corrected them

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `melka` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `melka`;
```